# Google optimize a/b test across multiple pages

Tags: google-optimize

Does anyone know how to use google optimize to create a split a/b test site wide.

I want to change the text on a button on  product pages of an ecommerce site but the same session is currently seeing both the original and the test version as they visit different products. Is there anyway to ensure the test is the same for the whole session of the user?

Example: the add to cart button says add to cart in the original and add to order in the test variant. If a user lands on a product page they see add to order but then as they navigate the site to a different product they eventually see the original add to cart. It’s not consistent across the session. I want them to be locked into that same test variant site wide.

Comment: Does your button have a consistent ID? E.g. on each page is it called #btnAddtoCart?